# Changing domain url in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Is it possible to change the website url in google analytics to a new domain and still keep old statistics. I tried changing it using "Edit" link below "Check Status" on the profile settings page, it changed on the settings page but it still appears with old domain to the left of UA Identifier on home page.

Comment: This looks like a bug/broken feature. You should post about it on the Google Analytics Forum; GA employees are pretty rigorous on there http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Analytics/label?lid=52d2f6b99ad2350e&hl=en

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics isn't domain specific so you should just be able to use the existing UA Identifier on your new domain and it will collect data.

I can't see of a way of editing the "Main Website Profile Information" but in theory it isn't necessary.

Comment: There IS a way to edit the Main Website Profile Information, (you click 'Edit'), but, as the OP said, its not working. Seems like a bug. But you're right that its not strictly necessary to change your domain in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics does not allow changing the old site address to a new one and saving the new one. And because of that, there won't be a change in the tracking code for the new address either.
With the old code placed on the new site, Google Analytics cannot track and analysis is that there are no visits to the site.

please for some reliable way.
I also tried placing the old registration in the trash, but a message appeared that I could not delete it.

The problem is not solved. Google should give more freedom of action in your personal profile. The fact that many people have this problem means that something needs to change

Answer (score 0):

Try the New Version of the interface, as described in [this post on the Google Analytics product group](http://productforums.google.com/d/msg/analytics/j5xTJxr7s18/b1ggWKCPC9kJ).

Answer (score 0):

If you use **"Tracking Info -> Subdomains"** feature You must substitute new tracking code.

this code line will be changed if you change website's domain.

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'yourdomain.net']);
```

==== >

```
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'yourdomain2.com']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
Yes, in Google Analytics you will not be able to replace the old site address with a new one or delete it for 2 days which is a protection during which time you will receive at least 2 emails and 2 SMS that someone is trying to do it.
If you are not you do not react and it will be possible in 2 days.
But if it's someone else, you can protect yourself.
Thanks Google